# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, selectlist

In my application I have the following message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title",ViewData["PersonTitle"] as SelectList, Model.Person.Title)
```

The dropdownlist contains simple strings (person titles). When you select a title, that title should be returned to my model.  Controller code:

```
ViewData["PersonTitle"] = new SelectList(new[] { "Dhr.", "Mevr." });
```

Why is this not working ?

Edit: The purpose is to change

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.Title)
```

into something like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title",ViewData["PersonTitle"] as SelectList, Model.Person.Title)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.Person` is null. You need to find out why this is not getting populated. The most common reason would be not outputing to the form so it does not get posted back.

Comment: ok, but i need to replace this part "@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Person.Type)" by a dropdownlist. And the value of that dropdown should be send to the same place as the editor would do. (Model.Person.Type)

Comment: Instead of `"Title"` it needs to be `"Person.Title"`

Comment: the "Title" after dropdownlist ?  that is just the name of dropdownlist. For avoiding misunderstanding, it is model.person.title and NOT model.Person.Type (could not change my comment anymore). If i use the editorfor(model=> model.Person.Type) , it send the value of what i wrote to the model

Comment: found it : had to use @html.dropdownlistfor

Comment: Yes, using generic extensions are 100 times better :) I did not recommend it to you since you were using ViewData but now it is good you have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

i had to use @html.dropdownlistfor